# How to Edit WelcomeText of User Interface Window of Visual Studio Installer Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

Is there a way to add version number in the WelcomeText property of User Interface window of Visual Studio Installer project? I know that it displays the property [ProductName] within the text area. I also want the Version property of the project displayed here.

Also is it possible to change the WelcomeText from the back-end using code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text in the WelcomeDialog is visible from the properties window of that dialog. It typically says:

The installer will guide you through the steps required to install [ProductName] on your computer.

[ProductVersion] is the version, so add it there somewhere, such as:

The installer will guide you through the steps required to install [ProductName] version [ProductVersion] on your computer.

Comment: Works like a charms. Thankyou Phil. :)

Comment: Is it possible to pick the value from assembly info version numbers of project?

Comment: Not with Visual Studio no, you'd need to somehow get the value out of the assembly and update the (I think) .vdproj file for the setup project before building it.